# Can anyone explain that how to print max and min in the code

Tags: python, random

1. This is a code
2. random is used in the code
3. the query is to find max and min value of z

   ```
    import random 
    x = random.randint(2,6)
    y = random.randint(1,2)
    z = x + y
    print(z)
   ```

Comment: This is not a programming question, just basic maths...

Answer (score 0):

Okay not a lot to go with but I think this is what you're trying to get:

```
import random
x = random.randint(2, 6)
y = random.randint(1, 2)
z = max(x, y)
print(z)
```

This would return the max value between x and y into the variable z

Comment: This is not what the question is about. It's about finding the minimal and maximal value that **z**, the sum of x and y, could take when generating random values of x and y in the specified intervals. So, there is no programming involved here, it's just (very) basic maths.

Comment: Actually i need to find the max value of z(x+y) not the individual values of x and y and also the code is not working and giving an error....

Answer (score 0):

If you want max and min values of z then you are going to need at least two values for z, perhaps more. I suspect there is a part of the question that will say how many.

Here is some pseudocode to help you:

```
// Set extreme initial values for max, min.
maxZ <- -1
minZ <- 1000

// Try a few values of z.
repeat
  // Generate one z.
  x <- random(2, 6)
  y <- random (1, 2)
  z <- x + y

  // Check for new max, min.
  if (z > maxZ) maxZ <- z
  if (z < minZ) minZ <- z
until (enough z's checked)

// Display results.
print "Max z = " maxZ
print "Min z = " minZ
```

Comment: I think this not a python code ....

Comment: It is not python, it is [Pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode). You will need to convert it to python yourself.